# Can't access NODE_ENV from ng2 app with webpack

Tags: node.js, angular, plugins, webpack, environment-variables

I'm trying to access NODE_ENV variable in the following way,

In `webpack.config.js`

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
        'API_URL': process.env.API_URL,
        'NODE_ENV': process.env.NODE_ENV
    }
});
```

Then in the app file: `app.config.ts`

```
export interface EnvVars {
    API_URL: string;
    NODE_ENV: string;
}

export const env: EnvVars = {
    API_URL: process.env.API_URL || '',
    NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV
}
```

And finally `auth.ts`

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { env, EnvVars } from "./../shared/app.config";
import {AuthModule} from "./auth.module";

if (env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
    enableProdMode();
}

console.log(env);

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AuthModule);
```

So this is the procedure i saw everywhere, and should be fine, but when y try to log the env variable within the app, I get the following output:

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0ZbE.png)

note that I can get the value of API_URL, but not the value of NODE_ENV, and both are set in the same way, `export ENV_VAR=value`.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on the way webpack replaces the vars, they should be defined with double quotes or JSON.stringify().

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Check whether NODE_ENV is set?

For Linux you can use:

```
printenv
```

For MAC:

Run `Env` command in terminal

I think while setting up the env variable there is possibility of misspelling.

Comment: you can pass env variable with webpack command like: webpack-dev-server --env=dev